# C# Сервер нарушил протокол. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#

Возникает ошибка: **Сервер нарушил протокол. Section=ResponseStatusLine**
Ссылку на ресурс дать не смогу. Кто-нибудь знает из-за чего возникает эта ошибка и как её устранить?

Код:

```
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://...");
            //Указываем системные учетные данные приложения.
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //Указываем сетевые учетные данные текущего контекста безопасности.
            request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "cmd_conf";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            richTextBox1.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            richTextBox2.Text = responseFromServer;
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: А заходит ли на этот сайт через браузер? Прийдётся вам посмотреть протокол снифером, сравнивайте дампы

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, через браузер можно зайти. А другого способа нет? Нельзя ставить стороннее ПО.

Comment: У вас часный случай. Либо смотрите сами что там у вас в postData, внимательно проверяте все параметры запроса. Либо разово пробуете помочь себе снифером (просто "дружеский" совет). Не все сниферы нужно устанавливать. Больше тут нечего добавить.